# Removing "List-Unsubscribe" from civimail headers (for when getting seemingly random unsubscribes)

Tags: civimail, extension, php

There is a "header" entry automatically put into mailnigs from civimail (also when using flexmailer / mosaico) which some email clients use to enable unsubscribing (or opting out) from mailing lists.

If, for example, an unsubscribe link is in your email, and the site is reporting opt-out's (or vice-versa) then this may be the reason why. So - how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @pradpnayak for guidance :D

according to the docs for hook_civicrm_alterMailParams:

> You can add custom headers by appending to $params['headers']. Example:
>
> ```
> $params['headers']['X-My-Header'] = 'my header value';
> ```
>
> The headers key may not exist in the $params array when passed into the > hook.

so this was the code in an extension to unset the existing 'List-Unsubscribe', and put in a NULL replacement into the headers:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_alterMailParams().
 *
 * @link http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_config
 */
function custom_civicrm_alterMailParams(&$params, $context) {
  if ($context == 'flexmailer' || $context == 'civimail') {
    // remove existing header
    unset($params['List-Unsubscribe']);
    // replace via the 'headers' key
    $params['headers']['List-Unsubscribe'] = NULL;
  }
}
```